# Subversion 1.9 - missing FSFS 7

Tags: svn, file-format, fsfs

im using Subversion Edge 5.1.4 with Subversion 1.9. The top-reason for using Version 1.9 is the new FileFormat Version 7 (better performance). But every time i create a new repo oder load a dump from an old one (with FSFS 4) - it only makes FSFS version 6.

How can i get a repo with FSFS version 7?

thx

Comment: Are you certain that you don't have an older version of Subversion hanging around on your server that is being used instead of 1.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN Edge 5.1.x is linked against Subversion 1.8.x. SVN Edge 5.1.4 is linked against Subversion 1.8.16, Apache 2.4.20, OpenSSL 1.0.1t. SVN 1.8 does not support FSFS format 7 repositories.

You can find more information at https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/svnedge/